# Using coroutines to fade in/out TextMeshPro Text Element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I am setting up a "scene intro" with some text saying 'Level 1' using TextMeshPro. I have created the text element in canvas and i am trying to find a way to make it fade in, then wait, and then fade out (Somewhat like what you see when you discover a new place in Skyrim).

So far i tried a versatile solution so i can use the same script for other uses (eg not in the start of the scene, not only fade in etc).

**Using TMPro:**

```
...
using TMPro;
...
```

**Start and declaration:**

```
public class IntroFade : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI textToUse;
    [SerializeField] private bool fadeIn = false;
    [SerializeField] private bool fadeOnStart = false;
    [SerializeField] private float timeMultiplier;
    private bool FadeIncomplete = false;

    private void Start()
    {

        if (fadeOnStart)
        {
            if (fadeIn)
            {
                StartCoroutine(FadeInText(timeMultiplier, textToUse));
                FadeIncomplete = true;
            }
            else
            {

                StartCoroutine(FadeOutText(timeMultiplier, textToUse));
            }
        }
    }
...
```

**Update in which i want to fadeout once fadein is done**

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (FadeIncomplete)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeOutText(timeMultiplier, textToUse));
        }
    }
```

**Corouritnes for the actual fading:**

```
private IEnumerator FadeInText(float timeSpeed, TextMeshProUGUI text)
    {
        text.color = new Color(text.color.r, text.color.g, text.color.b, 0);
        while (text.color.a < 1.0f)
        {
            text.color = new Color(text.color.r, text.color.g, text.color.b, text.color.a + (Time.deltaTime * timeSpeed));
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator FadeOutText(float timeSpeed, TextMeshProUGUI text)
    {
        text.color = new Color(text.color.r, text.color.g, text.color.b, 1);
        while (text.color.a > 0.0f)
        {
            text.color = new Color(text.color.r, text.color.g, text.color.b, text.color.a - (Time.deltaTime * timeSpeed));
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    public void FadeInText(float timeSpeed = -1.0f)
    {
        if (timeSpeed <= 0.0f)
        {
            timeSpeed = timeMultiplier;
        }
        StartCoroutine(FadeInText(timeSpeed, textToUse));
    }
    public void FadeOutText(float timeSpeed = -1.0f)
    {
        if (timeSpeed <= 0.0f)
        {
            timeSpeed = timeMultiplier;
        }
        StartCoroutine(FadeOutText(timeSpeed, textToUse));
    }
```

So what happens is it either fades in OR fades out depending on the Coroutine that starts first. I am not able to make it so it fades in, stays on screen for like 2 seconds and then fades out.

I also tried fading in then creating a coroutine to waitforseconds and then call the fadeout coroutine but that didn't work either.

Comment: Coroutines are fine but probably overkill. Have you tried an Animation? (You can animate almost anything in Unity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Coroutine can wait for the completion of another coroutine, thinking about it this way will simplify the problem immensely. You have already created your fade in and fade out, now you just have to run them in sequence with a 2 second wait between them.

```
private IEnumerator IntroFade (TextMeshProUGUI textToUse) {
   yield return StartCoroutine(FadeInText(1f, textToUse));
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
   yield return StartCoroutine(FadeOutText(1f, textToUse));
   //End of transition, do some extra stuff!!
}
```

If you are interested, [these articles](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2017/02/15/nested-coroutines-in-unity/#introduction) are pretty insightful when it comes to learning more about coroutines.

Comment: You don't even really need the `StartCoroutine()` part here. `yield return FadeOutText(1f, textToUse);` will work just fine.

Comment: Your solution absolutely worked. I don't know how i couldn't see it. And the articles are very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler and cleaner implementation would be to create one basic coroutine that functions for both fading in & out, or to any opacity for that matter.

```
IEnumerator FadeText(TextMeshProUGUI text, float duration, float newAlpha) {
    float originalAlpha = text.color.a;
    float elapsed = 0f;

    while (elapsed < duration) {
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        float alpha = Mathf.Lerp(originalAlpha, newAlpha, elapsed / duration);
        text.color = new Color(text.color.r, text.color.g, text.color.b, alpha);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This script uses a `Mathf.Lerp()` function to interpolate between the original alpha and the new alpha provided, along with a set `float duration` to control the duration of the transition. This script also allows you to transition into any alpha. For example if you want your text to start at full opacity and fade to 0.5, you can set the opacity of the text inside of unity to 1, and then change the `float newAlpha` to `0.5f`, and repeat when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off creating one routine with a delay method. For example im creating a main menu with numerous TMP buttons. The first button fades in after 7 seconds (giving splash enough time), the next has a a delay of 8 seconds, and so on. The buttons do not fade out, but after the fade in routine you can create a sub-routine that will fade out after a delay you can define in the script's inspector in unity.

I use LeanTween to do the fade in and out effects in my setup, since you cannot rely on transparency alone with TMP elements, it will not work. You need to manipulate the alpha instead.

Here is an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class TextMeshProButtonFadeIn : MonoBehaviour
{
public float fadeInTime = 1f;
public float fadeDelay = 0f;

private Button button;
private TextMeshProUGUI textMeshPro;

void Start()
{
    button = GetComponent<Button>();
    if (button == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Button component not found.");
        return;
    }

    textMeshPro = GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>.   .();
    if (textMeshPro == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("TextMeshProUGUI component not found as a child of the button.");
        return;
    }

    Color textColor = textMeshPro.color;
    textColor.a = 0f; // Ensure the text is initially transparent
    textMeshPro.color = textColor;

    LeanTween.alphaText(textMeshPro.rectTransform, 1f, fadeInTime)
        .setEase(LeanTweenType.easeInOutQuad)
        .setDelay(fadeDelay)
        .setOnComplete(() => Debug.Log("TextMeshPro button fade in complete")); // Optional callback when fade in is complete
 }
}
```